# Power BI slow cumulative visual using ALLSELECTED() - is there a faster way?

Tags: function, powerbi, dax

I have a measure which I have created to count distinct `'Data'[Files]` over a period of time. I managed to figure out that the `ALLSELECTED()` function is causing the visual to take long to load. This is the following code I am using;

```
Distinct files count = 
CALCULATE(
     DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[Files]), 
     ALLSELECTED('Data'[Date]),
     ISONORAFTER('Data'[Date], MAX('Data'[Date]), DESC)
   )
)
```

This chunk of code does provide the solution but the processing time is taking too long for requirements. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably the `ISONORAFTER` that is slowing down your visual. Try:

```
Distinct files count = 
  var maxD = MAX('Data'[Date])
  return CALCULATE(
     DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[Files]), 
     ALLSELECTED('Data'[Date]),
     'Data'[Date] <= maxD
  )
```

Adding 2nd option of creating a Calculated Table with the cumulative counts. This will slow dataset refresh but should speed up visualization at runtime.

```
ChartTable = 
  SUMMARIZE(
    'Data',
    'Data'[Date],
    "CumTotal",
      var maxD = MAX('Data'[Date])
      return CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[Files]), ALL('Data'), 'Data'[Date] <= maxD) 
  )
```

Comment: It's the ```ALLSELECTED``` which is causing the problem. I've replaced the ```ISONORAFTER``` and not getting any difference in render time

Comment: Can you share a snip of your visual?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot - sensitive information but its essential a cumulative line chart where the gradient always goes up or at the very worse side ways. There is never a downwards trend.

Comment: How many rows are there in your `'Data'` table? `ALLSELECTED` isn't slow and it depends on what your visual is doing. What do you have on the X-Axis of your chart?

Comment: around 8000 rows so not a lot. The X axis is dates

Comment: How many dates? Again, share a snip of the visual, feel free to mask out sensitive info.

Comment: Another thought, try creating a Calculated Table with the cumulative counts... `ChartTable = SUMMARIZE('Data', 'Data'[Date], "CumTotal", var maxD = MAX('Data'[Date]) return CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[Files]), ALL('Data'), 'Data'[Date] <= maxD) )`

Comment: That worked! The calculated table. Very very nice and thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, I've added the Calculated Table suggestion/option to the answer above. Please mark it as Accepted when happy.